# Getting field type in a method in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

How do I programmatically get the field type from a statement inside a method like this :

```
Foo foo = getSomeFoo();
```

If it is field, I can know the type of the element.

Comment: Are you asking how to find out the class of the object returned by getSomeFoo()? Is foo.getClass() what you need? I don't think I understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Eclipse's AST

```
ICompilationUnit icu = ...

ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
parser.setResolveBindings(true);
parser.setSource(icu);
CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
    @Override
    public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationStatement node) {
        System.out.println("node=" + node);
        System.out.println("node.getType()=" + node.getType());
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the class of the `foo` object by calling `foo.getClass()`.

If you have a class (or object) and want to programmatically get the return type for a particular method on that class, try this:

- Get the `Class` object for the class/object
- Call the [`getMethod()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) method and get a Method object back
- Call the [`getReturnType()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) method on the Method object

Comment: If you need more details on this, search Google for "Java Reflection"

Comment: i think he means from eclipse plugin